# Is $\sum_{j=1}^{k}a^j \equiv 0 \mod p\;$? where k is the order of $a \mod p$, with $p$ being an odd prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In other words is $a^1 + a^2 + \dotsm a^k \equiv 0\mod p\;$?

This is true when $a$ is a primitive root of $p$ because $a^1, a^2, \dotsc a^k$ are congruent to $1,2,\dotsc,p-1$ in some order. Hence, the sum is a triangular number of form $\frac{(p-1)(p)}{2}$ which is clearly divisible by p, i.e. is $0 \mod p$.

However the question is does this work for all $a$ $\textbf{not}$ being primitive root of $p$? E.g. take $p=11, a=3$.

We have $3^1\equiv3$, $3^2\equiv9$, $3^3\equiv5$, $3^4\equiv4$, $3^5\equiv1$, with the sum of these $\equiv22\equiv0 \mod11$.

If this is true, how would one go about proving this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: If $a=1$ then this isn't true.  For any other $a \ne 0,1$, multiply the sum by $a$, and it doesn't change.  Hence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $k=1\iff a=1?$

Else using Geometric Series $$\sum_{r=1}^ka^r=\frac{a(a^k-1)}{a-1}$$

Multiplicative Order $\displaystyle k\implies a^k\equiv1\pmod p\iff a^k-1\equiv0\implies a(a^k-1)\equiv0$

$\displaystyle\implies \frac{a(a^k-1)}{a-1}\equiv0\pmod{\frac p{\text{gcd}(a-1,p)}}$ (using $\#12$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html))

If $\displaystyle(a-1,p)=1$ for which,  "$p$ is a prime" is a sufficient condition

$\displaystyle\implies \frac{a(a^k-1)}{a-1}\equiv0\pmod p$